# How to tell TypeScript to continue a type in child code blocks?

Tags: javascript, typescript, class

Here I have a code that checks if this.loadMoreData is an instance of class LoadMoreData or LoadMoreDataGroup. And it works fine. But the problem is that TypeScript does not continue the checked type through the child code blocks inside the if statement (like callbacks of then and finally) and throws an error. What is the proper way to implement this?

```
if (isSingle(this.loadMoreData)) {
        this.loadMoreData.blockAction = true;
        this._fetchData()
          .then(r => {
            if (r === false) {
              this.loadMoreData.finishedData = true;
            }
            if (r !== null && r !== undefined) {
              this.loadMoreData.isFirst = false;
            }
          }).finally(() => {
            this.loadMoreData.blockAction = false;
            this.loadMoreData.mainLoading = false;
            this.cdr.detectChanges();
          });
      }else{
}
```

Comment: use type alias

inside the if condition say

const  loadData=  (this.loadData as YOURTYPE )

Answer (score 1):

The TypeScript way of achieving this is through the use of a type guard ([docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)). This will allow you to return the 'retyped' version of `this.loadMoreData` for use within the scope of the block that it is in. For example:

```
interface LoadMoreData {
  someKey: string
}
interface LoadMoreDataGroup {
  groupId: number;
}

isLoadMoreDataGroup(data: LoadMoreData | LoadMoreDataGroup): data is LoadMoreDataGroup {
  // Add logic here which can only be true if the type is LoadMoreDataGroup
  return (data as LoadMoreDataGroup).groupId !== undefined;
}
```

```
loadMoreData: LoadMoreData | LoadMoreDataGroup

handleData() {
  if (isLoadMoreDataGroup(this.loadMoreData)) {
    this.loadMoreData // LoadMoreDataGroup
  }
  else {
    this.loadMoreData // LoadMoreData
  }
}
```

Note `this.loadMoreData` will only be correctly typed within the scope of the block/function in which the type guard was used. As there is no type guard in the scope of this next function, it will not inherit the type check from the previous functions scope

```
someOtherFunctionCalledAfterHandleData() {
  this.loadMoreData // LoadMoreData | LoadMoreDataGroup
}
```